# Which files i should refer for simulation in contiki

Tags: c, contiki, iot

I am working on contiki as my academic work, now i have question which file i should refer specificaly from example folder in contiki for simulating schenario like - 30 node iot having ipv6 node , all these node send data to master / gateway node whenever any request come from outside that is from native linux host machine. So communication series is like any host outside IoT request some data from any of 30 IoT nodes via Gateway node/Border Router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the border-router look in `examples\ipv6\rpl-border-router` and for your nodes in `examples\ipv6\rpl-udp`. Then run the `tools\tunslip6` on your linux machine connected to the border-router through usb.

Have a look [here](http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/RPL_Border_Router).

Comment: thanks man i got idea i try it myself and give back comment whether i m on track or not..

Comment: Thanks you save my time. Now I want to retrieve / capture data (any yhing temp / humid or any word) from one node but from different sources, because my task is related to DoS attack identification.

Comment: I have 1 RaspberyPi board and 1 ARM7 is it helping me anyhow for this?? but i dont have any motes